# Error on creation of a PostgreSQL flexible server with .NET core 6, and Azure SDK

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, azure, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a problem with the creation of a postgresql flexible server using .net core 6.
The request seems to be correct. But looking on azure portal on activity log session, it always gave me this generic error:

Operation name: Update PostgreSQL Server Create
Error code: ResourceOperationFailure
Message: The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.

and, at code side this exception's message:

Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. 
Additional Info:'An unexpected error occured while processing the request. 
Tracking ID: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx'

I don't understand where the problem can be. Is there a way to get more details on the error? I think this is a too generic error.

Regarding my implementation, I generate the azure client using the class from azure sdk: Microsoft.Azure.Management.PostgreSQL.FlexibleServers.PostgreSQLManagementClient:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var client = new PostgreSQLManagementClient(credentials, new HttpClientHandler ());
client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

var response = await client.Servers.CreateWithHttpMessagesAsync(
    data.ResourceGroupName,
    "servername",
    new Microsoft.Azure.Management.PostgreSQL.FlexibleServers.Models.Server
    (
        location: "northeurope",
        sku: new Microsoft.Azure.Management.PostgreSQL.FlexibleServers.Models.Sku("Standard_D4s_v3", "GeneralPurpose"),
        administratorLogin: data.AdministratorLogin,
        administratorLoginPassword: data.AdministratorLoginPassword,
        version: "13"
    ), null, CancellationToken.None
);
```

This code causes an exception, with the error message mentioned above.

Where am I doing wrong?

**Problem solved thanks to Azure support. The storage size was missing. According to arm template:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/quickstart-create-server-arm-template?tabs=portal%2Cazure-portal#review-the-template**

Comment: `"I don't understand where the problem can be. Is there a way to get more details on the error? I think this is a too generic error."` Yes you can get more details, for doing so you have to enable [`app insight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/cloudservices) [you can check here for more details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/cloudservices)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MdFaridUddinKiron, but I found a solution for the problem

Comment: So what was causing the error?

Comment: I edited the main post yesterday, when I write the comment here ; )

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Franzkom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244614/franzkom) for the sharing the solution with us. Posting the same as answer to help other community members.

> Storage `skuSizeGB` was initially missed. Adding the same resolved the
> issue.